# Disabling a list item based on if a entry is locked or unlocked asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page at the moment, it has a model a view and a controller. However, I am looking to add some extra functionality. I am looking to add a padlock in a column, so if the table is locked then you cannot click on two list options in a drop-down button.

Model

```
public bool State {get; set;}
```

The controller I was thinking of doing

```
<tbody>
    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Songs.Count(); i++)
    {
        <td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></td>                     
            </td>
        </tr>
        tableRowIndex++;
    }
</tbody>
```

As ideally, I need to show a padlock only if it meets certain criteria. For the button so far I have just added `disabled` to the list. But then I need to change the tooltip that is in Bootstrap to something completely different.

Comment: `public bool State bool {get; set;}`?? that's strange

Comment: You have an opening `<td>` when it should be a `<tr>`